# Python ConfigParser printing empty array {}

Tags: python, printing, sections, configparser

```
import configparser

def editConfig():

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    host = "10.99.77.1"
    url = "http://" + host + "/Config/config.ini"
    print(url)

    print(config.read(url))
    print(config.sections())
```

For some reason my program is only printing an empty array. Yes, I am accessing the config file from another device over it's wifi, so I think this may be the problem, but when I put the whole url in my browser as I'm connected to the device I can see the config file just fine. Do I have to download the file onto my computer first and then use the parser then? I've looked at many other examples of ConfigParser and mine seems in line with them.

I've already double-checked that I have downloaded and updated ConfigParser for Python3.6

Comment: I cannot access that config file; what is in it?

Comment: read() ignores files it cannot open. If print(config.read(url)) is printing an empty array then this means it cannot open the file from that URL. Try read the file separately and then parse with read_string()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate method to actually get the file and/or its contents. I'm a fan of requests, but there are several solutions.

I also sort of want to caution you - unless this is a S3 bucket or something similar with specific permissions set up - which from the code you share it doesn't look as if it is - you aren't really gaining the security that's the main point of using an ini for configuration. If the file just has stuff you don't need to be secured, that's fine, but having it at a URL you can open in your browser is apocalyptically bad if it has, say, your AWS keys.